# Can't see notification colors today

Tags: bug, notifications

Is it just me?

I can't see notification colors properly today. I'm on SO and the inbox doesn't get red anymore and the rep icon only sometimes shows a very faint shade of green. (If it helps matters: The faint Green looks like the color of earning a a badge)

Comment: Nope, not just you, and not even just Stack Overflow.